# Child Theme not working - CSS gone

Tags: functions, child-theme

I'm using the Twentyeleven theme for my new site. I created a child-theme so I can modify the theme and not have my changes overwritten.
But once I activate my child-theme the whole styling is gone. I guess the issue lies in the functions.php. Maybe I did something wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my functions.php in my child-theme:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

Comment: <?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `get_template_directory_uri()` to load files from the parent theme. `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is for the current theme, which is your child theme.